# AutoHotKey: Double press script from SetTimer malfunctioning

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

If a letter has modifiers and is being sent on this double press script from [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm), the triggering key`s preceding modifier(s), in this case shift, will be included on the letters along with any existing ones already on the letter.

With the script bellow, F is being sent because shift is being added to ^A for some reason.

This does not appear to occur with numbers or keys that need to be inside of { }, such as {F1}.

Any clue?

```
; Testers:    
+^A:: Send, F    
^A:: Send, T    
    
+^B:: Send, F    
^B:: Send, T    
    
; Malfunctioning double press:    
    
+PGDN Up::    
if (SHIFTPGDN_presses > 0)    
{    
    SHIFTPGDN_presses += 1    
    return    
}    
SHIFTPGDN_presses := 1    
SetTimer, KeySHIFTPGDN, -300    
return    

KeySHIFTPGDN:    
if (SHIFTPGDN_presses = 1)    
{    
    Send, ^A    
}    
else if (SHIFTPGDN_presses = 2)     
{    
    Send, ^B    
}    
SHIFTPGDN_presses := 0    
return
```

Comment: FYI, you can put 4 spaces in front of each line of code to make it appear in a separate block of recognizable code on StackExchange

Comment: Thanks for the editing tips. Found the mistake also: A is +a not only while typing, but also while sending keys, so I just needed to put ^a and ^b instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what's happening, but you can try using `SendInput` or `SendMode Input` (sometimes has slight differences with `Send` / `SendPlay`).

Another command you can try is `KeyWait`, which can be used to wait until the original modifier is let up.  That may not have the desired effect though as it induces a delay until you let off the modifier.

Another thing you can try is to send the actual modifier up, such as `Send {Shift Up}` or `Send {Ctrl Up}`.  This can also introduce issues in certain cases but can also be helpful sometimes depending on what you're doing.

And if you're trying to trigger a hotkey from another hotkey, you may need to look at `SendLevel` (I don't think you're doing that from a quick glance at your code, but just FYI).

Comment: Thanks for the editing tips. Found the mistake also: A is +a not only while typing, but also while sending keys, so I just needed to put ^a and ^b instead.

Answer (score 0):

The script has to wait for the PGDN key to be released for executing the commands:

```
+PGDN::    
if (SHIFTPGDN_presses > 0)    
{    
    SHIFTPGDN_presses += 1    
    return    
}    
SHIFTPGDN_presses := 1    
SetTimer, KeySHIFTPGDN, -300    
return    

KeySHIFTPGDN:  
KeyWait, PGDN  ; wait for the PGDN to be released 
if (SHIFTPGDN_presses = 1)
    Send, ^a   
else if (SHIFTPGDN_presses = 2)
    Send, ^b 
SHIFTPGDN_presses := 0    
return
```